How to force React Native Animated.timing to use only integers?
I need to force only integers in the range of values between the initial Animated.Value() and the toValue.
If there is another library for this type of animation, it's enough for my case.
this myValues = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

      Animated.timing(this.myValues, {
        duration: 2000,
        toValue: 500,
        easing: Easing.ease,
        useNativeDriver: false,
        delay: 0,
      }),

From 0 to 500 I want only integers. Is it possible?
